# Problems implementing undo/redo with vectors in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, vector, command

I'm currently working on a project for a class, where we are using C++ to implement simple functionality into a text editor. We have simple commands, such as inserting a character, moving left, inserting a new line, and then we have an undo/redo feature, where undo simply undoes whatever the last command was. And redo will redo whatever command was just undone.

To start, I have a base class called `Command` where I derive all my other classes for implementing these commands. So far, each of my commands work as expected, and undoing and redoing simple combinations of these commands will work.

I implement the functionality for undo/redo in my `CommandProcessor` class by using two vectors:

```
std::vector<Command*> undoVector; // used for undo
std::vector<Command*> redoVector; // used for redo
```

When a command is issued, it goes to a certain statement within an if-else and I store that command inside the `undoVector`. When undo is called, before undoing the command, I store the command from that vector in `redoVector`. When I redo a command, I store the command about to be redone in `undoVector` and issue a command to execute it.

When the user hits exit, I free the vectors memory by using this method:

```
void freeVector(std::vector<Command*> &element) {
    for(int i = 0; i < element.size(); i++)
    {
        delete element[i]; // delete command object
    }
    element.clear(); // clear vector
} // end free vector
```

In my program, it should **always** be possible to get back to the state the program started in, by using undo, which looks like this (where | is the position of my cursor):

```
1. |
```

Currently though, if I issue too many commands to undo, I redo a couple of those commands, then I insert some more commands, undo those, and then redo those, I can't undo to the start of my program. It gets stuck at a random command and won't go any farther.

Running memcheck, it shows this error:

```
==24048== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==24048==    by 0x805CCE0: (anonymous namespace)::freeVector(std::__1::vector<Command*, std::__1::allocator<Command*> >&)
```

Below is how I am currently implementing my undo and redo vectors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
void CommandProcessor::run()
{
    bool commandInteraction = false;
    std::vector<Command*> undoVector; // used for undo
    std::vector<Command*> redoVector; // used for redo
    view.refresh();
    while (true)
    {
        UserInteraction interaction = nextUserInteraction();
        if (interaction.type == UserInteractionType::quit)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (interaction.type == UserInteractionType::undo) // UNDO
        {
            try
            {
                if(undoVector.empty())
                {
                    throw EditorException("Nothing to undo.");
                } else {
                    interaction.command = undoVector.back();
                    redoVector.push_back(interaction.command);
                    interaction.command->undo(editor);
                    commandInteraction = false;
                    undoVector.pop_back();
                }
            }
            catch (EditorException& e)
            {
                view.showErrorMessage(e.getReason());
            }
            view.refresh();
        }
        else if (interaction.type == UserInteractionType::redo) // REDO
        {
            try
            {
                // if the redo stack is empty -> we can't redo
                // if the last known state was at command -> we can't redo
                if(redoVector.empty() || commandInteraction == true)
                {
                    freeVector(redoVector);
                    throw EditorException("Nothing to redo.");
                } else {
                    interaction.command = redoVector.back();
                    undoVector.push_back(interaction.command);
                    interaction.command->execute(editor);
                    redoVector.pop_back();
                    view.clearErrorMessage();
                }
            }
            catch(EditorException& e)
            {
                view.showErrorMessage(e.getReason());
            }
            view.refresh();
        }
        else if (interaction.type == UserInteractionType::command) // COMMAND
        {
            try
            {
                interaction.command->execute(editor);
                commandInteraction = true;
                undoVector.push_back(interaction.command);
                delete interaction.command;
                view.clearErrorMessage();
            }
            catch (EditorException& e)
            {
                delete interaction.command;
                view.showErrorMessage(e.getReason());
            }
            view.refresh();
        }
    } // end while
    freeVector(undoVector);
    freeVector(redoVector);
} // end run
```

Comment: use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Command>>` and you don't have to worry about manually deleting or inadvertently double-deleting the objects stored in the vector.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious If I use that, would I just have to replace everywhere that I use freeVector with delete? Or is it handled once the function exits?

Comment: You won't even call delete. Any time an element is removed from the vector it's automatically deleted. If you call `clear()` on the vector every element is automatically deleted.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious How should I use push_back or pop_back on the vectors? I tried doing `undoVector.push_back(std::move(interaction.command));` but it says: `error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'`

Comment: It is my fault again: by 0x805CCE0: (anonymous namespace)

Comment: Side note: you should clear `redoVector` when you get `UserInteractionType::command`.

Comment: @AntonSavin Just did this and it solved my issues. Thank you!

Comment: @AntonSavin Debug a programmer's program, and you improved his program today. *Teach* a programmer to debug, and you've improved his coding for a lifetime.

Comment: @Alex You can do printf debugging to spot where your logic fails (e.g. the redoVector not being empty). Don't rely on stackoverflow to debug your programs.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator that note wasn't actually about debugging, I thought OP just didn't fully understand undo/redo logic.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator The project was given in a state where printf wouldn't work (it would crash the program). We were given a "debugger" that our teacher made. However, it didn't work in the class that we were supposed to implement undo/redo, so I spent a few hours trying to debug in my other classes where I implemented the functions, but I couldn't get a clear picture of what was going on.